# Javascript: Search and highlight includes HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so i'm making this code that when the user searches for a query in a textbox, it will highlight the query somewhere in the content and focuses on the first occurence of that query. Problem is that when the user types in something like **li** or **div** which are HTML tags, those also appear as search results. For example, here is my html markup

```
<div class="col-lg-6" id="search-area">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id="search-term" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button id="search-button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
</div>

<h3>Did we miss something? Have any more FAQs to add? Contact us directly at blabla@gmail.com</h3>
```

and here is my js

```
    function searchAndHighlight(searchTerm, selector) {
if(searchTerm) {

    var selector = selector || "#mainContainer"; 
    var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm,"ig");
    var matches = $(selector).text().match(searchTermRegEx);
    if(matches) {
        $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');     //Remove old search highlights
            $(selector).html($(selector).html()
                .replace(searchTermRegEx, "<span class='highlighted'>"+searchTerm+"</span>"));
        if($('.highlighted:first').length) {             //if match found, scroll to where the first one appears
            $(window).scrollTop($('.highlighted:first').position().top);


        }
        return true; 

    }
    }

    return false;


    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search-button').on("click",function() {
    if(!searchAndHighlight($('#search-term').val())) {
        alert('No results found for query "'+$('#search-term').val()+'".');
    }else{
        alert($("span[class='highlighted']").length);
    }
    });

    $("#search-term").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        if(!searchAndHighlight($('#search-term').val())) {
            alert('No results found for query "'+$('#search-term').val()+'".');
        }else{
            alert($("span[class='highlighted']").length);
        }
    }
    });


    });
```

if the user inputs **h3** for example, the result will be

```
<**h3**>Did we miss something? Have any more FAQs to add? Contact us directly at blabla@gmail.com</**h3**>
```

shouldn't it say that there are no results found?

Comment: i forgot, here is my js file

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change you code to interate over all the children nodes and check their val() instead of their html():

```
....
  var selector = selector || "#mainContainer"; 
    var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm,"ig");
    var matches = [];

    $.each($(selector).children(), function(index, item){
        matches.push($(item).val().match(searchTermRegEx));
    });

    if(matches) {....
```